# Can I use the If-Unmodified-Since header to prevent duplicate report runs?

Tags: rest-api, reporting

I see from the [REST API developer page on conditional requests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_rest_conditional_requests.htm) that I can add the If-Unmodified-Since header so that "the request is processed only if the data hasn’t changed since the specified date."

First, does using this header actually reduce the number of requests serviced by Salesforce, as counted toward the daily transaction limit?

Second, can this be used when running reports so that the report is not run (and counted against the 500/hour report max) if the report content hasn't changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First, does using this header actually reduce the number of requests serviced by Salesforce, as counted toward the daily transaction limit?

No, you still get charged the API call. The purpose of those headers is to save bandwidth, not reduce API usage.

> Second, can this be used when running reports so that the report is not run (and counted against the 500/hour report max) if the report content hasn't changed?

No. The headers tell you what's supported (e.g. describes), and that's all you get. Second, even if it was supported, the system would still need to query the database to calculate the hash to see if the report changed. Again, the purpose is to save bandwidth, not server-side resources.